# Errors when using kable. Issues with phantomjs or ghostscript?

Tags: r, phantomjs, ghostscript, kable, kableextra

I am trying to create a table in R. I used mtcars as ax example dataset. I keep getting the error below. I am truly at a loss for how exactly to fix this and where to move certain files or programs to (ghostscript, magick, phantomjs..). Is there an easy fix? I am not using markdown.

```
kable(rawCSV, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("solid", "scale_down")) %>%
  as_image()
  save_kable(file="table.pdf")


Error in save_kable_latex(x, file, latex_header_includes, keep_tex, density) : 
  We hit an error when trying to use magick to read the generated PDF file. You may check your magick installation and try to use magick::image_read to read the PDF file manually. It's also possible that you didn't have ghostscript installed.
```

Comment: Could you please try to run your code by adding `%>%` next to `as_image()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gives the same error :(